# Output from watson assistant and watsonx, doesnt match

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I tried to make Order ID Bot, that can generate automatically ID from customer input using WatsonX and try to integrated it to watson assistant.

I tried to make this prompt:

[image]

[image]

And if i tested it to watson assistant it would be like this :

[image]

I wish someone can help me, to fix this problem

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Prompt lab in watsonx is for testing out prompts only. You can't (at this time) reference a prompt you created or assume that the prompt you are working on is referenced.

To solve you need to send the prompt along with your input from Assistant.

You can check if this is the case by going to the Extension inspector in Assistant. It will show you the payload you sent and the response. This way you can see the prompt mis-match.